# String replace space

Tags: php, regex, string

I have two string like this:

```
$a = "John, Male , Central Java";
$b = "name = John and gender= Male";
```

I want these string to become:

```
$a = "'John','Male','Central Java'";
$b = "username='John' and gender='Male'";
```

What pattern and replacement would work with preg_replace to accomplish this?

I want to create a function like this:

```
function select($what, $from, $filter) {
    $query = "SELECT $what FROM $from WHERE $filter";
    // Performing mysql query.
}

$result = select("*", "user", "username = John and gender = Male");
```

$quer Output: `SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = John and gender = Male`

But the output is not valid mysql syntax. So I want the output to become:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='John' and gender='Male'
```

I also want to remove the space between symbols.

**Solution:**

I have try some pattern and replacement and finaly I found the solution. I've create function to format the query string. I also change the string setting with using `&&` as `AND` and `||` as `OR`. So, even when the value string contains 'and' or 'or', it's would not affected by preg_replace.

```
// Preg replace sample: -> string = string space && string = space
function format_query($qry_string) {
    // Remove spaces before and after '='.
    $qry_string = preg_replace("/(\s+\=)/", "=", $qry_string); 
    // string= string space && string= space
    $qry_string = preg_replace("/(\=\s+)/", "=", $qry_string);
    // string=string space && string=space

    // Add single quote between '=' and word than contain space after the word.
    $qry_string = preg_replace("/\=(\w+\s+)/", "='$1", $qry_string); 
    // string='string space && string=space

    // Add single quote in first and end of words that start after '=' and not contain space after the word.
    $qry_string = preg_replace("/\=(\w+)/", "='$1'", $qry_string); 
    // string='string space && string='space'

    // Add single quote in end of words before of keyword '&&' and '||'.
    $qry_string = preg_replace("/(\w+)\s+\&\&/", "$1' &&", $qry_string); 
    // string='string space' && string='space'
    $qry_string = preg_replace("/(\w+)\s+\|\|/", "$1' ||", $qry_string);

    // Replate keyword '&&' and '||' to 'and' and 'or'
    $qry_string = str_replace("&&", "AND", $qry_string);
    $qry_string = str_replace("||", "OR", $qry_string);

    return $qry_string;
}

$string = "realname = Nanang El Agung || username = sarjono && password = 123456";
echo format_query($string);
```

OUTPUT: `realname='Nanang El Agung' OR username='sarjono' AND password='123456'`

This function is works fine for `$b` above.

Comment: You can use regex: split string into arrays, then `implode()`.

Comment: If you use PDO, you could just use http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

This just does that, for the first example, test it.

```
<?php 

$a = "John, Male , Central Java";


foreach ((explode(",", $a)) as $one) {

echo '\''.$one.'\',';
}
```

Outputs

```
'John',' Male ',' Central Java',
```

In relation to the Mysql query, something like this is feasible.

```
<?php 

    $a = "John, Male , Central Java";


    foreach ((explode(",", $a)) as $one) {
```

.

```
 function select($one) {  // will run the three statements, relatively..
```

.

```
   echo '\''.$one.'\',';
    }
```

**Second one**

---

```
$b = "name='John' and gender='Male'";

$b = str_replace('name', 'username', $b);

foreach((explode("=",$b[1]))as $one){
echo "$b";
}
```

Comment: Yes, the first sample is working. But how about the $b? It's containg " and " that need to splited as well. I think i can't explode it using "and" as pattern, since sometime this is a part of word, not keyword. e.g. `select("*", "table", "field like me and you and name = John")`, then the output will be `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field like 'me and you' and name='John'`

Comment: Ok, give me some minutes, I'll see what I can do

Comment: @NanangElSutra sorry, for being late, I can not seem to find a way to put a `'`  around the names, but you can see my updated title --second one

Answer (score 2):

Using [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$a = "John, Male , Central Java";
$b = "name = John and gender= Male";

$a = preg_replace('/(\w+)((\s?\w+)+)/', '\'$1$2\'', $a);
// 'John', 'Male' , 'Central Java'

$b = preg_replace('/name\s?=\s?([\w\s]+) and gender\s?=\s?([\w\s]+)/', 'username = \'$1\' AND gender = \'$2\'', $b);
// username = 'John' AND gender = 'Male'
```

**\w** => [a-zA-Z0-9_]

**\s** => space

**+** => 1 or more characters

**?** => 0 or 1 character

Answer (score 1):

The second part is

```
function select($what, $from, $filter) {
$query = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT {$what} FROM {$from} WHERE {$filter}")); extract($query);
return $what;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do it.** You're trying to construct an SQL query with regular expressions. Your code (including all three current answers) will break on the first `O'Connor` that walks in the door. If you were to fix this and somehow get your code on the web, you'll be at the mercy of the first hacker who'll try a series of well-known exploits until they find a corner case you didn't think about.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496), for the full details and the proper way to build your SQL statements.

Comment: Hi @alexis, thanks for notice. I have know about that, but currenlty i'm building php framework to forward the query to multiple db engine. I also build some function to makes some query more easy. e.g. `_data::batch_insert('users|bio', 'username = john | passwd = 123456 | gender = male');` Although users type `DELETE TABLE` in their input, it's would automatically quoted by functions since every function only escape words from quotes if they are operator like `&&` as `"and"` or `<>` as `"LIKE"`. Users can also validate their string with `validate_string()`. Thanks.

Comment: Run your functions on the string `"realname = John; DROP TABLE user"`. Then re-read my answer, and the linked-to question.

Comment: Oh, function in my question is only sample. In my final function: `$input = "realname = John; DROP TABLE users; DROP TABLE address; exit;`. Then when I call my function the output is: `realname='John; DROP TABLE users; DROP TABLE address; exit;'`. I have try many SQL command and all output is quoted. Thx.

Comment: Sample? Then try "realname = John'; DROP TABLE users;", or whatever. Judging from your "sample", your code is definitely full of problems. Enjoy the ride.